# Using esdoc for jsx files

Tags: reactjs, jsx, esdoc

I want to generate document for `.jsx` files

**.esdoc.json :**

```
{
   "source": "./src/",
   "destination": "./doc" 
}
```

But `esdoc` just use `.js` files in `./src` to generate document.

So **how do i config esdoc to generate document for .jsx files?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  "includes": ["\\.(js|jsx)$"],
```

I do not recall, but I may have had to modify the esdoc package to accept jsx.